# Using Express.js and node.js to get a select from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to print the query but it doesn't show nothing. I cant't to figure out why the code doesn't work. The connection works but the query doesn't.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password'
});

connection.query('USE database');

app.set('port', 3001);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT * from test', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('this is the result = ', rows[0].field);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect to the database, by writing:

```
connection.connect();
```